# substrings consisting of max 2 of 3 characters

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to write a regex that would match all substrings in a string that contain repetitions of max 2 characters in `['a', 'b', 'c']`

So a string like `abcccbaaa` should have these matches:

```
ab
bc
bcc
bccc
cc
ccc
cccb
ba
baa
baaa
```

What I have so far is: `a+a*|a+b*|a+c*|b+a*|b+b*|b+c*|c+a*|c+b*|c+c*`
but this doesn't match a string like `abab`. I also tried wrapping each individual combination like this: `(a+a*)+` but it's not working too well. Is this possible with regex?

Comment: Are you limited to using regex only?

Comment: @rukh-ta Well yes I'm trying to do it with regex. I know the other solutions, I'm just trying to see if its possible with regex too.

Comment: why not `cb` in the result?

Comment: @jean-francoisfabre Yeah it should be there.

Comment: `a+a*` is the same as `a+`.

Comment: `re.findall()` won't find overlapping matches, so it can't return both `bc` and `bcc`.

Comment: @barmar oh I didn't know what. what function can I use instead?

Comment: I think it might be possible if you use *regex-lookbehind*.

Comment: @ninesalt I don't think there's anything that will do it. Also, a regular expression is either greedy (returning the longest match) or non-greedy (non-greedy), there's no way to get all the possible lengths.

Comment: What you need to do is get all substrings, and test each of them to see if they match the pattern with `^` and `$` anchors.

Comment: @barmar Okay so if I didn't want shorter matches, how would I just find the longest match?

Comment: Iterate over the indexes of the string, and use `re.match()` with the substring starting at that index.

Comment: If `cc` and `ccc` are in expected matches then `aa` and `aaa` should also be there

Answer (score 0):

The expression you are looking for is : (a+|b+|c+){2}

The problem is that re.findall() will not overlap matching patterns so:

```
re.findall("(a+|b+|c+){2}","abcccbaaa")
```

will only find consecutive (non-overlapping) matches: "ab", "cccb" and "aaa".
(i.e. since the first "b" is part of the "ab" match, it is not considered for a "bc" match)

In order to get all the overlapping patterns, you would have to execute re.match() iteratively on your string, removing characters up to the first character of each match and executing re.match() on the rest until you find no more matches.  You would also need to apply the search recursively on larger matches because they could contain smaller matching patterns as well (e.g. bccc contains bcc and bc). Finally, you would probably want to eliminate duplicates from the result (e.g. ccc is actually two overlapping cc patterns).

I don't think you'll be able to do this within a single regular expression but you could do it in an iterative function:

```
import re

def multiMatch(pattern,string):
    result = []
    match  = re.match(pattern,string)
    while match:
        subString = string[match.start():match.end()]
        result.append(subString)
        result   += multiMatch(pattern,subString[:-1]) # see note below
        string    = string[match.start()+1:]
        match     = re.match(pattern,string)
    return list(set(result))

sorted(multiMatch("(a+|b+|c+){2}","abcccbaaa"))

>>> ['aa', 'aaa', 'ab', 'ba', 'baa', 'baaa', 'bc', 'bcc', 'bccc', 'cb', 'cc', 'ccb', 'ccc', 'cccb']
```

*note: At that point you only need to check for smaller patterns from the beginning of the subString.  I was lazy and simply called the function recursively but this is not optimal as it will generate sub matches that will be caught again by the main loop just to be eliminated by list(set(result)).*